# HTML JavaScript delay downloading img src until node in DOM

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I have markup sent to me from a server and I set it as the innerHTML of a div element for the purpose of traversing the tree, finding image nodes, and changing their src values. Is there a way to prevent the original src value from being downloaded?

Here is what I am doing

```
function replaceImageSrcsInMarkup(markup) {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = markup;
  var images = div.getElementsByTagName('img');
  images.forEach(replaceSrc);
  return div.innerHTML;
}
```

The problem is that in browsers as soon as you do:
`var img = document.createElement('img'); img.src = 'someurl.com'` the browser fires off a request to `someurl.com`. Is there a way to prevent this without resorting to parsing the markup myself? If there is in no other way does anyone know a good way of parsing the markup with as little code as possible to accomplish my goal?

Comment: If your goal is to not download the original source, perhaps replace the new source before setting the innerHTML.

Comment: That's the alternative I mentioned but there is no good way to do that. Anyways I just realized there is no issue here. This actually works fine because I change the src before the end of javascript execution.

Answer (score 2):

I know you are already happy with your solution, but I think it would be worth sharing a safe method for future users.

You can now simply use the [`DOMParser` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) to generate an external document from your HTML string, instead of using a `div` created by your current `document` as container.

DOMParser specifically avoids the pitfalls mentioned in the question and other threats: no `img` `src` download, no JavaScript execution, even in elements attributes.

So in your case you can safely do:

```js
function replaceImageSrcsInMarkup(markup) {
    var parser = new DOMParser(),
        doc = parser.parseFromString(markup, "text/html");

    // Manipulate `doc` as a regular document
    var images = doc.getElementsByTagName('img');

    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i += 1) {
        replaceSrc(images[i]);
    }

    return doc.body.innerHTML;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/94b7gyg9/1/

Note: with your current code, browsers will still try downloading the resource initially specified in your `img` nodes `src` attribute, even if you change it before the end of JS execution. Trace network transactions in this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/94b7gyg9/

Answer (score 0):

Rather than append the new markup to the DOM before you change the img sources, create an element, set it's inner HTML, change the source of the images and then finally, append the changed markup to the page.

Here's a fully-worked sample.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
"use strict";
function byId(id,parent){return (parent == undefined ? document : parent).getElementById(id);}
//function allByClass(className,parent){return (parent == undefined ? document : parent).getElementsByClassName(className);}
function allByTag(tagName,parent){return (parent == undefined ? document : parent).getElementsByTagName(tagName);}
function newEl(tag){return document.createElement(tag);}
//function newTxt(txt){return document.createTextNode(txt);}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

window.addEventListener('load', onDocLoaded, false);
function onDocLoaded()
{
    byId('goBtn').addEventListener('click', onGoBtnClick, false);
}

var dummyString = "<img src='img/girl.png'/><img src='img/gfx07.jpg'/>";

function onGoBtnClick(evt)
{
    var div = newEl('div');
    div.innerHTML = dummyString;

    var mImgs = allByTag('img', div);
    for (var i=0, n=mImgs.length; i<n; i++)
    {
        mImgs[i].src = "img/murderface.jpg";
    }
    document.body.appendChild(div);
}
</script>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
<button id='goBtn'>GO!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, an `img` element does not need to be inserted into DOM for the browser to start downloading the resource… That is exactly why the OP was asking for a workaround. This behaviour is also a security threat if you attempt to perform user input sanitization by generating a node tree even outside DOM. An attacker can write `<img src="dummy" onerror="alert('owned');" />` and have arbitrary JS executed in the page context. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/94b7gyg9/

Comment: I used to work at FB it was for an experiment to delay loading images below your viewport but it was no bueno

Answer (score 0):

You could directly parse the markup string using a regex to replace the img src. Searching for all the img src urls in the string and then replacing them with the new url.

```
var regex = /<img[^>]+src="?([^"\s]+)"?\s*\/>/g;
var imgUrls = [];
while ( m = regex.exec( markup ) ) { 
    imgUrls.push( m[1] );   
}

imgUrls.forEach(function(url) { 
    markup = markup.replace(url,'new-url'); 
});
```

Another solution might be, if you have access to it, to set the all the img src to an empty string, and put the url in in a data-src attribute. Having your markup string look like something like this
    markup = '
        
        
    ';

Then setting this markup to your div.innerHTML won't trigger any download from the browser. And you can still parse it using regular DOM selector.

```
div.innerHTML = markup;
var images = div.getElementsByTagName('img');
images.forEach(function(img){
    var oldSrc = img.getAttribute('data-src');
    img.setAttribute('src', 'new-url');
});
```